# Typewriter backwards/remove preserve html tags

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, text, tags

I need to make a reversed typewriting effect. Problem is that I need to preserve the html-tags too.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/mSmm9/

```
var str = 'Foo is <b>not</b> equal to bar.';
var remove = false;
var i = 0;
var isTag;
var text;

(function type() {
    if (remove) {
        text = str.slice(0, --i);
        if (!text) return;
    }

    if (!remove) {
        text = str.slice(0, ++i);
        if (text === str) return;
    }

    document.body.innerHTML = text;

    var char = text.slice(-1);
    if( char === '<' ) isTag = true;
    if( char === '>' ) isTag = false;

    if (isTag) return type();
    setTimeout(type, 100);
}());
```

Currently it works only if we let it type forward. If we go backwards (backspace-alike) the opening/closing brackets are visible:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/mSmm9/1/

Any ideas how to fix this?

I tried to swap the opening and closing tags `<` & `>`:

```
if( char === '>' ) isTag = true;
if( char === '<' ) isTag = false;
```

no success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right to swap the `<` & `>` tags but you also needed to start at the end of the string and move backward like so using your example and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvz8S/1/):

```
var str = 'Foo is <b>not</b> equal to bar.';
var remove = false;
var i = str.length;
var isTag;
var text;

(function type() {
  if (!remove) {
      text = str.slice(0, --i);
      if (text === str) return;
  }

  if(!isTag) { document.body.innerHTML = text; }

  var char = text.slice(-1);
  if( char === '>' ) isTag = true;
  if( char === '<' ) isTag = false;

  if (isTag) return type();
  setTimeout(type, 100);
}());
```

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that, added so that the innerHtml isn't updated on those runs causing the flickering.

Comment: Ok, this results in another problem... Since you moved the setter `document.body.innerHTML = text;` writing forwards doesn't work anymore!

Comment: Ha Ha, well to tell you the truth if you're going to make this work both ways I would clean up the code a bit, so you want to make the effect for forward and back, give me a bit and I can give you a better way.

Comment: also do you plan on supporting and `<` or `>` in the sentence other than tags? Say the string: "x > y output: <b>yes</b>".

Comment: Sounds great! The code above is just small piece of what I've done yet. Here's a gist of the actual state: https://gist.github.com/yckart/6425600/9fa98fb6f27b27bf1e41e2db51a93d7a1ae2b07a#file-index-js-L81-L102

Comment: @yckart here you are jsfiddle.net/CmCkY/2 it doesn't fix your < and > that aren't tags but thats an interesting thing I'll leave you to figure out